# Python - Complementary gear shape

Tags: python, matplotlib, edge-detection, concave-hull

I'm trying to find the complementary rotary "gear" shape to any input polygon shape. For example this polygon, is rotated around so that the complementary gear becomes apparent. Both shapes would be able to rotate without interferences.

I'm having issues defining the second polygon, which is the edge of the white inner region. One method I can think of is "sampling" the input shape along its circumference, and rotating like before to generate a pointcloud. A concave hull algorithm (Alpha shape) could be used to obtain the edge.

While this would work, I feel there must be a more elegant solution to this problem.

Thanks

[image: gears]
Polygon and its rotated image

[image: sampled shapes]
Sampled polygon and resulting pointcloud

[image: zoom edge]
close up of edge

Comment: It's not clear what produces the shown plot to the right in terms of the polygon on the left. If you rotate the polygon about a point, the resulting shape would be a circle.

Comment: The polygon is rotating around the center like the earth around the sun. It circles the center at some offset and revolves around its own axis at the same time

Comment: Can you just provide the formula or code in the question? (I don't see how the polygon can be the earth with the sun in the earth's center, but that's probably anyway not what you mean.)

Comment: If you define your polygon in polar coordinates, i.e. as `r1(theta)`, then the meshing gear is `r2(theta) = R - r1(theta)`, where `R` is the distance between the centers of the gears.

Comment: Am I right to think that the complementary gear is made of arcs of cycloid ? If true, the challenge is to find the intersection between the cycloids and determine the useful sections.

Comment: @NominalAnimal that was my first thought as well, but it does not work. It results in interference at some points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good point. It seems to be part of the solution, or cycloids bent around a circle

Comment: @CyrielN: or isn't it a circle involute ? The theory of gear curves should tell you.

Comment: @CyrielN: Oops, you're right: it is not sufficient to examine the intersection on the line between the centers, one must also ensure the gears do not interfere elsewhere. I wonder if you can model the complementary gear as a geometric subtraction from a disk? (I.e, disk is rotated clockwise by the same angle as gear is rotated clockwise, and for all angles, the gear shape is subtracted from the disk.) That should take care of the interference issues. Or is this just another way of stating what you implemented in the question already? (Such gears may not transfer torque, just rotate together.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal That approach is certainly valid. It would result in jagged edges at some of the internal "cuts". 
Torque transfer is not a requirement. This is more an aesthetic project. However, what is the requirement for torque transfer? I guess the angle of the tangent through point of contact, which is constant for involute gears if I remember correctly.

Comment: @CyrielN: I think there are many different definitions, depending on whether you need torque transfer in one direction only, or in both directions. For example, if the contact is always on one side of the line through the rotation centers, you can ensure torque transfer in one rotational direction -- you can verify this by examining the force vectors. For practical gears, wear and backlash are very important, and for involute gears, the contact points roll (as opposed to slide). Herringbone gears have multiple contact points and force vectors.. I'd love to play with 3D printed gears. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The solution is to track all vertices and a special point for each edge. Then, the inner gear shape can be extracted by doing an intersection of all obtained curves.

The contact point on the edges is the point on that edge which is closest to the instantaneous rotation center of the gear, which is the point where the two base circles touch.

I'm using shapely to do the intersections.

I tried uploading the gif but that didn't work, so here is a link:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/nuYUv03ZWTYpFJrq2

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I solved it. The solution is to track each vertex and contact point on each edge. The contact point is the point **on that edge** closest to the instantaneous rotation center, which is the point where the two base circles touch.

I then use shapely to find the intersection of all obtained shapes, which represents the inner gear.

I tried uploading a gif, but that's not working so here it is instead:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/nuYUv03ZWTYpFJrq2

[image: test]